# D3 interactive h-bar

Tags: d3.js

I'm using this code

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("div.h-bar").on("click", function(){
   d3.select(this).style("width", function () {
      return (d3.mouse(this)[0])+"px";
   })
   .select("span")
   .text(function (d) {
      return (Math.round(d3.mouse(this)[0]/10)/10);
   }); 
})
```

for interactively change the width of any h-bar clicking on, with the mouse and it works fine, but only to reduce the width ...
It's probably a focus issue ...  Do you have an idea to increase the width ?

Comment: have you got a fiddle we can view ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, after you reduce the width of the `h-bar`, clicking outside of the div will not fire div's click. So you will have to bind the listener to the outer container of the `h-bar` div.

Hope this helps. Share more code if still have issues.

```js
d3.select("body").on("click", function() {
  d3.select(this).select(".h-bar").style("width", function() {
      return (d3.mouse(this)[0]) + "px";
    })
    .select("span")
    .text(function(d) {
      return (Math.round(d3.mouse(this)[0] / 10) / 10);
    });
})
```

```css
.h-bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="h-bar"></div>
```